# ALAssetsGroup! is not a subtype of 'ALAssetsGroup'

Tags: closures, swift, ios8

I have a `loadAlbums` method in my app that loads assets using a singleton instance of the `AssetsLibrary`. Here is my code so far:

```
func loadAlbums(){
    let library = IAAssetsLibraryDefaultInstance

    library.enumerateGroupsWithTypes(ALAssetsGroupAll as ALAssetsGroupType,
        usingBlock: {(group:ALAssetsGroup, stop:Bool) in
            if group {
                self.albums.append(group)
            }
            else {
                self.tableView.performSelectorOnMainThread("reloadData", withObject: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
            }
        }, failureBlock: { (error:NSError) in println("Problem loading albums: \(error)") })

}
```

The error I am getting is at the beginning of the `usingBlock` line. The compiler says:

`ALAssetsGroup! is not a subtype of 'ALAssetsGroup'`

What does this mean? How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you please explain why my question was marked down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your block is expecting an `ALAssetsGroup` for the `group` argument, but it's being passed a an argument with type `ALAssetsGroup!` (an implicitly unwrapped optional).

The big difference is that the value you're being passed **can** be nil, but the type you're expected **can not** be nil

just change your signature to

```
{(group:ALAssetsGroup!, stop:Bool) in
  …
}
```

your code is already checking if group is nil, so that should be the only change you need to make

Comment: Ok that helped but now on the `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` line, the compiler is saying: `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'Void'`

Comment: @AmitErandole That is a weird error, and honestly I don't know the answer to it, (perhaps you need `-> Void ` in the block signature?) but you may have better luck submitting a new question about that error